# PAGER('/dev/null'): permission denied

Tags: octave

Setting PAGER to `/dev/null` as suggested through the net to prevent every command being printed in stdout issues an error under OS X 10.6:

```
octave:1> PAGER('/dev/null');
octave:2> 1
sh: /dev/null: Permission denied
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: What is the first thing you should look at?  The permissions of /dev/null.  What are they?  From that you should be able to figure out your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like grawity said above, Octave is indeed expecting PAGER to be set to a program, but `cat` raises an error, `true` raises a broken pipe warning.

So, figured Octave was just piping output to PAGER, and fixed this by redirecting the output of a valid program  to `/dev/null`:

```
PAGER('less > /dev/null')
PAGER('true > /dev/null')
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is shown because Octave is expecting PAGER to be set to a *program* that can be run and given the text as 'stdin'. The `/dev/null` file is obviously not a program, and it does not have the "executable" permission bot; the latter is what causes the permission error.

Try `/usr/bin/cat` or `/usr/bin/true` instead.